# Finding all instances where a foreign key appears multiple times grouped by month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am not too familiar with SQL, and I have been tasked with something that I quite frankly have no clue how to go about it.

I am just going to simplify the tables to the point where only the necessary fields are taken into consideration.
The tables look as follows.

```
Submission(course(string), student(foreign_key), date-submitted)
Student(id)
```

What I need to do is produce a table of active students per month, per course with a total. An **active student being anyone who has more than 4 submissions in the month**. I am only looking at specific courses, so I will need to hard code the values that I need, for the sake of the example "CourseA" and "CourseB"

The result should be as follows

```
month | courseA | CourseB | Total
------------------------------------------
03/2020    50       27        77
02/2020    25       12        37
01/2020    43       20        63
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation: first by month, course and student (while filtering on students having more than 4 submissions), then by month (while pivoting the dataset):

```
select
    month_submitted,
    count(*) filter(where course = 'courseA') active_students_in_courseA,
    count(*) filter(where course = 'courseB') active_students_in_courseB,
    count(*) total
from (
    select 
        date_trunc('month', date_submitted) month_submitted,
        course,
        student_id,
        count(*) no_submissions
    from submission
    where course in ('courseA', 'courseB')
    group by 1, 2, 3
    having count(*) > 4
) t
group by 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this has just saved me from hours of pain.

Answer (score 0):

You could do subqueries using the `WITH` keyword like this:

```
WITH monthsA AS (
    SELECT to_char(date-submitted, "MM/YYYY") as month, course, COUNT(*) as students
    FROM Submission
    WHERE course = 'courseA'
    GROUP BY 1, 2
),  monthsB AS (
    SELECT to_char(date-submitted, "MM/YYYY") as month, course, COUNT(*) AS students
    FROM Submission
    WHERE course = 'courseB'
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)
SELECT ma.month,
       COALESE(ma.students, 0) AS courseA,
       COALESCE(mb.students) AS courseB,
       COALESCE(ma.students, 0) + COALESCE(mb.students, 0) AS Total
FROM monthsA ma
LEFT JOIN monthsB mb ON ma.month = mb.month
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```